# Intersection between 2 polygons

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon

I have two polygons (one rectangle and one triangle), I want to have a function (poly_intersect) that gives me the intersection between these two polygons.
[related image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqpUD.png)

```
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
polygon1 = pd.DataFrame([[2,2],[4,2],[4,4],[2,4],[2,2]],columns=['X','Y'])
polygon2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[3,3],[3,6],[1,3]],columns=['X','Y'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6, 4))
ax.add_patch(matplotlib.patches.Polygon(polygon1.values,color='blue',alpha=0.5))
ax.add_patch(matplotlib.patches.Polygon(polygon2.values,color='green',alpha=0.5))
ax.axis([0,5,1,7])


vertices = poly_intersect(polygon1,polygon2)
```

expected output:  `[[2,3],[3,3],[3,4],[2,4]]`

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Where are you stuck? Have you got any error? Where?

Comment: Why also `[2,4]`? and why `[2,3]` is counted twice?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego, I am new to SO and not familiar with the rules. However, for this specific question, I do not have any idea to start with. I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution, that's why I posted the question only without any try.

Comment: @Joe, the intersection has 4 corners and `[2,4]` is the fourth corner. I removed the repeated point.